# GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database from the following flow chart: https://www.learncodinganywhere.com/learningmanagementsystem/links/07_DB/SQL_Drill.pdf

If I am trying to find how many copies of a certain book title are in each Library_Branch.BranchName, what method would I use to do that? I know if I wanted to get the number of all the copies in every branch I could do this:

```
SELECT sum(No_Of_Copies) as 'Total Copies' 
FROM BOOK_COPIES 
WHERE BookId in (select BookId 
                 from book where title like '%The Great Gatsby%')
```

But I am having trouble trying to figure out how I would distinguish each branch and the number of copies. Please no direct answers if possible!

Trying to figure this out on my own, its on the tip of my tongue, just need a little guidance. 
Edit: Is this getting closer? I feel as if i'm almost there.

```
     SELECT sum(No_Of_Copies) as 'Total Copies' FROM BOOK_COPIES
        WHERE BookId in 
        (
        select BookId 
        from book where title like 
        '%The Great Gatsby%'
        ) Group By BranchName in
        (
        SELECT BranchName
        from LIBRARY_BRANCH
        )
```

Comment: Title is the answer, Add the `branch` info in  `GROUP BY` and `Select` so for each branch grouping will happen

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER, it works for me on my end. And ok I will try to go from that!

Answer (score 0):

```
select lb.BranchName, b.Title, sum(bc.no_of_copies) 
    from Library_Branch lb
    join Book_Copies bc
    on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
    join Books b
    on bc.BookId = b.BookId
    group by lb.BranchName, b.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Branch, title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as 'Total Copies' 
FROM BOOK_COPIES 
INNER JOIN BOOK
ON Book_Copies.BOOkID = Book.BOOKID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Branch
ON Branch.BranchID = BOOK_Copies.BranchID
WHERE Book.title like '%The Great Gatsby%'
GROUP BY Branch, Title
```